Spark UI - executor TAB wrong input value
I've been trying to understand why my executor tab is showing me only 3.1TiB input, when in fact my job reads at least 11TB (s3 total sizes).
I have multiple jobs and just in just one of my DAGs I can see it reading 6.3TiB (already more than executors tab).
Is it not accounting for filtered out records? Or is it a bug?
EMR job reading from S3.
Any ideas?
Thanks.


